# Entity Framework Core: ThenInclude with involving Join Entity

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

In EF Core, many-to-many relationships need to be expressed by explicit join entities. In one case I have the following relationship:

```
A <---- 1:1 ----> B <---- m:n ----> C
```

which is expressed as:

```
A <---- 1:1 ----> B <---- 1:n ----> JOIN ENTITY <---- n:1 ----> C
```

OK, I want to query A including B and the C instances referenced by B.
Within my LINQ expression, I do the following:

```
return SomeQuery()
            .Include(j => j.B)
            .ThenInclude(p => p.ReferenceToJoinEntity);
```

Now the query resolves B, the list of join entities, but not the C entities, as this would be the grand-grand-child. 
Another `ThenInclude` does not seem to work as it would operate on the `IList` collection type, not the Join Entity type.

Any ideas how to query the list of C entities?

Comment: *Another ThenInclude does not seem to work* Please show the non-working code. Also, it's better to show the classes. You may overlook code that causes side effects.

Comment: Ignore the Intellisense and just type in at the end `.ThenInclude(j => j.C)`

Comment: Thank you, this worked nicely. I did not even try it as I trusted Intellisense - just saw that there seems to be an open issue.